# Foursquare create Access Token faile

Tags: oauth-2.0, token, foursquare

I want to create an access token for my foursquare app. 
I've tried it with an PHP library and runscope.com

I always geht this message from foursquare, after I've clicked on "create token" (please note, I translated this text from German into English):
"Connection failed: This app hast got an configuration problem and couldn't make a connection to your facebook-account.
Cause of Error: Callback uri is not valid for this consumer."

I think the callback uri is the redirect uri - but that doesn't work. Is this false? What have I to do?
Can anybody help me or have an idea?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the `redirect_uri` in your OAuth URL **matches exactly** what you have in your app settings page on Foursquare.